# How to call a class objects's method if it is not assigned to a variable in python?

Tags: python, class, methods

Please see the code below, how do I call the `GetCurrentSelection()` method of `Choice()` object below? `Choice()`  object is not assigned to a variable.

```
import wx

class ChoiceFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Choice Example', 
                size=(250, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sampleList = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five',
                      'six', 'seven', 'eight']
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Select one:", (15, 20))
        wx.Choice(panel, -1, (85, 18), choices=sampleList)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    ChoiceFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

If it was written this way:

```
choice_object = wx.Choice(panel, -1, (85, 18), choices=sampleList)
```

Then I would do:

```
choice_object.GetCurrentSelection()
```

But it has no variable names, so how will I call `GetCurrentSelection()` method in original code above?

Comment: Why not just change the code so you do have it saved in a variable?

Comment: @Duncan I can, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do this way.

Comment: @Wooble I don't see any relation, I don't want to get the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search through all the children of your top panel looking for it but since you also haven't given it a name you would be hard pressed to match it - the best bet is to assign anything you need to interface with later to a self.member e.g. `self.myChoice = ...` or even to an array or dictionary member of `self`.

The other option, if you just don't like adding it to the properties list, is to extend the class so that on creation it takes a data item to associate with, initialises to the current value and binds the appropriate change events to setting the value in that item.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, you could call the `GetCurrentSelection` method when you create the `Choice`:

```
wx.Choice(panel, -1, (85, 18), choices=sampleList).GetCurrentSelection()
```

I don't know why you're not just storing the choice, though. Variables exist for a reason.